# no suitable method found for showMessageDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Employee Id Is  "+
 empid , "\nEmploye Name is  " + employeename ,
"\nFather Name is " + fathername ,
"\nJob Catagory is  " + jobcatagory,
"\nAge is  " + age,
"\nEducation is  " + education,
"\nPay Scale is   " + payscal,
"\nNIC is  " + NIC );
```

am getting this error

```
no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    method javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int,javax.swing.Icon) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: What do you think the error means? Look at your method call, specifically the numerous `,`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `,`  instead of + for String concatenation

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Employee Id Is  "+
 empid , "\nEmploye Name is  " + employeename +
"\nFather Name is " + fathername +
"\nJob Catagory is  " + jobcatagory +
"\nAge is  " + age +
"\nEducation is  " + education +
"\nPay Scale is   " + payscal+
"\nNIC is  " + NIC );
```

And you are passing wrong arguments to the showMessageDialog() method.

Please refer the JOptionPane and its method signature [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Comment: This still isn't the solution, as the first argument represents the `parentComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

javax.swing.JOptionPane provides three overridden methods:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int,javax.swing.Icon) 
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int)
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)
```

And you was calling a method which is not defined in that class:

```
showMessageDialog(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

I guess there is something wrong with "," instead of "+".

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the null before your output statement as in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "....");
and you cant use "," only "+"

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your text "+anyVariable+"any more text",
    "The BoxHeader title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

You have to put `null` first, then don't forget the "Box header title" followed by a comma (,) and the `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`